# Customizing the Templates FormHelper for just plugins CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to customize a form helper template for just a plugin, not across the App.

```
Example: 'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-control">{{content}}</div>',
```

How do I go about doing this in CakePHP 3?

Answer (score 1):

[As per the docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses) - to change theme inline at runtime use `setTemplate`:

```
$myTemplates = [
'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-control">{{content}}</div>',
];
?>
<?= $this->Form->create('Users') ?>
<? $this->Form->setTemplates($myTemplates); ?>
<?=
$this->Form->input('email', [
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'templates' => [
        'formGroup' => '{{input}}{{label}}'
]])
?>
```

You can't use the `templates` option on the Form for a dynamic template, it will only look for a config file listing template items in `/config`.

Comment: Thanks for quickly responding, my plugin has several .ctp files that this change needs and it feels like a lot of manual work to edit each .ctp file that has a form helper to use the custom template. Is there are dynamic way to set this for a plugin specifically.

Comment: I think you can do the same thing using a custom helper but it will take the same amount of time in existing functionality. otherwise you need to make it global